# Race conditions in API calls within Golang microservices

Tags: postgresql, go, heroku, microservices, race-condition

I have a microservice architecture running on Heroku. I am having some problems handling race conditions.

The problem is, that service `A`:

- Needs to fetch the user's balance through an API call to service `B`, then
- if balance is large enough, make a withdrawal though an API call to service `C`.

I have noticed that if service `A` receives two requests in quick succession (a duplicate request), then the two operations will race to make the call to `C`. Thus, the user can end up with two withdrawals, and a possible illegal negative balance.

To further complicate things, on this production environment, microservices will generally run on multiple Heroku dynos. So I think this makes it impossible to utilize Golang's `sync.Mutex`. Potentially, I could consider adjusting this service to use a single dyno to allow the use of mutexes.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Use transactions in a database to ensure consistent update of the application's data.

Comment: If using db transactions is not possible, use a service like redis or zookeeper to coordinate distributed transactions.

Comment: What you can do is add a queueing mechanism, you can use apache pulsar to register a withdrawl request with a specific topic and a separate service which will listen on the topic and serve the requests. Here you can use threads and multiple listeners to speed up your process. There are certain types of listeners which will allow you to send the request from a single source/user to be handled by a specific listener thus allowing you to handle race condition.